# Laravel-5 get last inserted id after firstOrCreate()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the last inserted ID in the database after a firstOrCreate() call. I have copied my code below:

```
$booking->firstOrCreate(array_slice($reserve->whereId($payment->reserved_place_id)->first()->toArray(), 0, 24))->save();
```

How can I get the last ID inserted?

I have looked at the other Laravel requests to get last insert ID but I believe this instance is different because they are not using firstOrCreate().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

`firstOrCreate()` method returns Model. So you can simply save it to some variable and then get the model's ID.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Returns always a model as stated in the [Laravel documents](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment):

> There are two other methods you may use to create models by mass assigning attributes: firstOrCreate and firstOrNew. The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the given attributes.

```
$flight->id; //returns the last inserted id or the id of the already created document
```

Comment: When I do `dd($booking->id)` after the above call it just returns `null`

Comment: Try doing this way `$booking = App\Booking::firstOrCreate(array_slice($reserve->whereId($payment->reserved_place_id)->first()->toArray(), 0, 24));`